# C# how to prioritize multiple display modes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm in a situation, where multiple display modes apply.
Something like:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("a")
{
    ContextCondition = context => AFunctionThatReturnsTrue()
});

DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("b")
{
    ContextCondition = context => ADifferentFunctionThatReturnsTrue()
});
```

What I'm experiencing is that in this case always the display mode "b" is applied.
The question is: **what I've to do in order to have the display mode "a" picked instead?**

What I've tried, and have not worked:

- I've tried to change the order of the registration.
- I've tried changing the name of the display mode, so that display mode "b" is alphabetically before "a".

Comment: Did you use different `ContextCondition` for them or you have same for both? if not system would have problem with guess when to display which.

Comment: @MarcinCiesla `ContextCondition`s are different, but both evaluate to `true`. I'm going to update the question to better reflect this. Thanks

Comment: Ok, lets go further with your situation. 
Are you 100% sure that only one condition is happening at the time you are reaching for display mode? 
To achieve proper mode being displayed you need to assure that only this condition is meet.
if you have **A** condition and **B** condition set as true as same the time it's still confusing for application.

Comment: @MarcinCiesla yes, that's exactly my situation... `AFunctionThatReturnsTrue`, and `ADifferentFunctionThatReturnsTrue` return `true` at the same time. I supposed that there is some sort of prioritization for such cases. It seems I am wrong from what you've said.

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize it by setting proper index:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("a")
{
    ContextCondition = context => AFunctionThatReturnsTrue()
});

DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("b")
{
    ContextCondition = context => ADifferentFunctionThatReturnsTrue()
});
```

This should assure that mode **A** will be provided before **B** even if both conditions are met.

**EDIT:** 
This is not backed by any official documentation, but I tried it in my project and it worked.

Comment: Mmm... that's not working for me. Also I don't get how this is different from just changing the order of the `insert`s